# On the probability that a Poisson RV is less than k given it is not equal to k

Tags: terminology, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

Let

$$
X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda) \\
p = P(X \lt k | X \ne k; \lambda) \\
p = \frac{\text{CDF}(k - 1; \lambda)}{1 - \text{PMF}(k; \lambda)}
$$

Questions:

1. Does $p$ - i.e. in words the probability that $X$ is less than $k$ given it is not equal to $k$ - have some specific name?
2. Is there an efficient way to calculate $\lambda$ given $k$ and $p$? As opposed to simple numerical optimisation

Answer (score 0):

(1) Not to my knowledge

(2) Since you know your variable is Poisson, you know the expression for the CDF and PMF. You then solve for $\lambda$ in the following formula:

$$p= F(k-1) = \frac{1-e^{-\lambda (k-1)}}{\left(\tfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}\right)}.$$

This fried Wolfram Alpha, but I’m sure that some root-finding algorithm will help you. Since you explicitly say thay you are not interested in numerical solvers, from my knowledge there are no closed-form expressions for $\lambda$ in terms of well-known functions

Comment: Did you read the question?

Comment: Now I did correctly answer 50$\%$ of it, I just didn’t expect the question to be what it is as it’s so unconventional

Comment: I appreciate you giving the question your attention but I specifically said not numerical optimisation for 2

Comment: I see, yes I’m in a bit of a rush and I assume certain questions will be of the more conventional type. No, there isn’t any nice closed form solutions for this expression in terms of well-known functions